# Updating ResultSets in Querulous?

Tags: scala, twitter, squeryl, querulous

How do I update ResultSets in Querulous?  For example, I have a legacy application that does not have its password encrypted.  I want to go back and bcrypt all these passwords using some bcrypt java library.

Here's a solution I came up with using ScalaQuery, encrypting one month's of data at a time, since there are a lot of records (though I'm not sure this matters, so feel free to comment if you see something wrong with my implementation).

I already have an idea of what it would look like in squeryl, so I'm interested in seeing how this would look in Querulous:

```
package chubaka

import org.scalaquery.session._
import org.scalaquery.session.Database.threadLocalSession
import org.joda.time.DateMidnight
import java.sql.Date

import org.scalaquery.ql._
import org.scalaquery.ql.TypeMapper._

import org.scalaquery.ql.extended.OracleDriver.Implicit._
import org.scalaquery.ql.extended.{ExtendedTable => Table}

import org.scala_tools.time.Imports._
import org.mindrot.BCrypt

object MembershipUpdate {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    case class MembersElement(id: String, password: String, dateCreated: String)

    val Members = new Table[(String, Option[String], Option[Date])]("MEMBERS") {
      def id = column[String]("ID", O.PrimaryKey) // This is the primary key column
      def password = column[Option[String]]("PASSWORD")
      def dateCreated = column[Option[Date]]("DATECREATED")
      // Every table needs a * projection with the same type as the table's type parameter
      def * = id ~ password ~ dateCreated
    }

    // Connect to the database and execute the following block within a session
    Database.forURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@//test.chubaka:1521/legacydb", driver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver") withSession {
      // The session is never named explicitly. It is bound to the current
      // thread as the threadLocalSession that we imported

      def bcryptPassword(password: String) = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt())
      def dtToSqlDT(dt: DateMidnight) = new Date(dt.toDate.getTime)

      var month = new DateMidnight(new DateMidnight().withDayOfMonth(1) + 1.months)

      while (month > new DateTime(2006, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)) {
        val prevMonth = month - 1.month

        val q = Members.where{ p => 
          (p.password isNotNull) && (p.dateCreated >= dtToSqlDT(prevMonth)) && (p.dateCreated < dtToSqlDT(month))
        }

        q.map(_.password.get).mutate(m => m.row = bcryptPassword(m.row))

        month = prevMonth
      }
    }
  }
}
```